# Split Array after char

Tags: php, arrays

Hey there I'd like to split an Array into an multidimensional Array:

The actual code:

```
public function getUrlParameters() {
    $actual_link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    return $url = explode('/', $actual_link);
}
```

The actual output:

> Array ( [0] => [1] => request?search=hello [2] => test )

What I'd like to have:

> Array ( [0] => [1] => request ([0] => ?search=hello) [2] => test )

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP explode and assign it to a multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463420/php-explode-and-assign-it-to-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: @PaulS sorry I don't found that poste. I hope so.

Comment: @marvin_fritz php has better methods to return query as array

Comment: https://gist.github.com/salines/cf6536d423171559dc67e788050e1a43